# An error is reported when referring to variables in the module: Variable'bar_1m' isn't initialized yet

Tags: module, dolphindb

Can I only define functions in Modules?

I load some of the Table inside the Module, for example,

```py
Bar_1m = loadTable bar_1m
```

"the DFS: // Kline", "bar_1m" , but in the use of this module, when I references after bar_1m, the system will complain Variable'bar_1m' is not initialized yet.

Answer (score 0):

In the module file, only encapsulated function definitions are allowed, and other non-function definition codes will be ignored